# Sorting techniques: example radix sort

Tags: sorting, radix-sort

Challenge how to do this?

Apply radix sort on the following:

```
A = {cat,bat,cow,sit,may,why}
```

Comment: How do you want it to be sorted? Alphabetically? Length?

Comment: [wiki article on radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Least_significant_digit_radix_sorts)

Comment: alphabetically ofcourse coz length is same

Answer (score 1):

To perform the radix sort, you must first understand the intended results at each stage.

When you begin the radix sort, you will have your elements assigned as so:

```
{cat,bat,cow,sit,may,why}
```

In the first iteration, we will go from top to bottom and sort according to alphabetical order according to the last letter. This will result in:

```
{cat,bat,sit,cow,may,why}
```

In the next iteration, we will go from top to bottom and sort according to alphabetical order according to the second to last letter. This will result in:

```
{cat,bat,may,why,sit,cow}
```

Finally, we repeat this method with the first letter. This will result in your sorted words:

```
{bat,cat,cow,may,sit,why}
```

When you implement, you'll have to consider the data that you will be getting. Are you guaranteed to always have the same length for each string? Radix will only work on sets where all the lengths are the same. If this isn't always the case, you can consider allowing the program to add characters to a string in such a way to make the lengths equal and compare the strings in the proper fashion.

Additionally, the runtime for this radix sort will be O(L(n+k)) where L represents the length of your strings and n represents the number of strings you have to sort. The k represents the range of values you could have. If your strings only used characters "A" through "D", it would be 4. Assuming you're evaluating the whole alphabet, k will be represented by 26.

Hopefully this helps you understand radix sort a bit better. If you're free to use any algorithm though, I would recommend using whatever alphabetical sorting algorithm is built-in with the language you're using.